# Fundamental Forms and Surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

My question is about the fundamental forms of a surface.

Let's say that the coefficients of the first fundamental form are {E, F, G}.

And the coefficients of the second fundamental form are {e=E, f=F, g=G}.

I was wondering is it possible and what does it imply?

My first observation, the Gaussian curvature becomes 1 and it implies that the surface is a unit sphere. And it is also my final observation:).

Thanks for your resposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remark about Gaussian curvature is right, while the second one is wrong: Gaussian curvature is local invariant, hence the surface you decribed is locally isometric to a sphere, but not necessarely the unit sphere: consider an open subset $U\subsetneq\mathbb S^2$: clearly $E=e$, $F=f$ and $G=g$, but $U\ne\mathbb S^2$.

Comment: You are right, I will edit my answer

Comment: Thank you for clearing my mind.